# Use of 'female' and 'male' (in science fiction)

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Often in science fiction when someone refers to a male or female member of some other species, they use terms like "the klingon female". This also happens between members of that species, so if a Klingon was to refer to a female of their own species, they would refer to her as a "klingon female". For me as a native German speaker, this sounds rather weird as in German this kind of wording would only be used when referring to animals (e.g. female dog) and it sounds rather derogatory. When referring to humans, in German you would always use the equivalent words for "woman" or "man". I have also (rarely) seen that usage in English language non-science fiction movies used on humans.

So my question is, in English is the use of "female" or "male" to describe a person of either the same or an equal species derogatory or not? Are there any connotations to that that I don't get? Is this usage fine among humans (in the real world)?

Comment: Use of "the female" for "the woman" predates science fiction. See James Fenimore Cooper, _The Heidenmauer_ : "The door opened, and the female stood confronted to the person of the anchorite. The cloak and hood both fell from the female's head, as by an involuntary weakness of her hand—and each stood gazing long, wistfully, and perhaps in doubt, at the other. The female, more prepared for the interview, was the first to speak."

Comment: @SvenYargs For another example there are versions of the early 19th C folk song [Bonny Bunch of Roses-O](http://www.joe-offer.com/folkinfo/songs/35.html) which begin "By the dangers (or margin) of the ocean / one morning ( or pleasant evening) in the month of June / The sweet feathered warbling songsters their charming notes so sweet did tune / 'Twas there I spied a **female** seemingly in grief and woe,
Conversing with young Buonaparte concerning the bonny bunch of Roses O!". As the song progresses the **female** turns out to the Empress Josephine.

Comment: @SvenYargs depending of course on your definition, [SF predates Fenimore Cooper by some time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_science_fiction).  Certainly *Frankenstein* came before *The Heidenmauer*, and Frankenstein's creation says "You must create *a female* for me with whom I can live in the
interchange of those sympathies necessary for my being.  This you alone
can do, and I demand it of you as a right which you must not refuse to
concede." [emph. mine]

Comment: "You will be required to select from the Matrix 23 individuals - 16 female, 7 male - to rebuild Zion." - we can debate all day about how that's derogatory, but none of those words are.

Comment: This of course assumes that an alien species even has two genders in the same way that humans and other Earthling animals do.  Assuming they evolved entirely independently from humans, there's no guarantee that these aliens wouldn't be entirely genderless, or hermaphroditic/parthenogenetic (possessing traits of both or capable of self-impregnation), or have more than two genders, or even be able to switch genders at will, which some real creatures on Earth already can do.

Comment: It's ugly, but there just aren't suitable words in English at all. "Klingon man" or "Klingon woman" is wrong unless you are talking about a hybrid.

Comment: Same happens in fantasy as well, at times. Sarah J Maas in particular is fond of referring to her male fae characters as "the brooding male" or whatever, the same way that anyone else would use "man" (and for the same reason as your Klingon examples; a fae is not a man).

Comment: @Mazura the slight difference there is that your quote uses them as adjectives qualifying "individual", rather than as nouns.  I'm not sure whether this amounts to anything but it works well for humans.

Comment: *"It doesn't matter when its Arcturian."*

Comment: The inhabitants of the planet Elektroun take the form of either plugs or sockets.  The plugs are called "male" and the sockets "female".

Comment: @Andrew Leach I don't want to attempt any argument in Comments or through additional Answers and yet your intercession against my Posted Answer is too much to let pass.

Will you please try to justify your view in Chat, at least?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Police regularly use *male* and *female* as nouns or adjectives, a convention often imitated by news outlets:

> AKRON, Ohio — Police say two [*males*](https://www.cleveland.com/metro/2019/01/male-shot-after-being-robbed-of-marijuana-in-akron-2-suspects-in-custody.html) robbed another *male* of marijuana and then shot the victim in the ankle when he chased after them. — Cleveland.com, 16 Feb. 2019.
>
> Around 9:30 a.m. Monday, a [*male*](https://www.njherald.com/20190117/suspect-arrested--in-td-bank-robbery#) entered the TD Bank in Franklin and handed a teller a handwritten note instructing her to give him an undisclosed amount of cash, Mattessich said. … The suspect was described as a black male with a medium build and facial hair wearing a grey checkered jacket. — *New Jersey Herald*, 17 Jan. 2019.
>
> Police say a lone [*male*](https://lfpress.com/news/local-news/police-investigating-armed-robbery-west-of-london) came in to the store with a weapon. No physical injuries were reported, police said. — *London Free Press* (UK), 14 Jan. 2019.
>
> The [*female*](https://www.theage.com.au/national/victoria/detectives-question-suspect-in-fatal-cyclist-hit-run-in-south-yarra-20180814-p4zxar.html) cyclist was treated by emergency services but died at the scene. — TheAge.com (Melbourne), 14 Aug. 2018.
>
> On Tuesday, March 13, 2018, a [*female*](https://www.ottawapolice.ca/Modules/News/index.aspx?feedId=027e4532-b9a7-41cc-a991-fa1e92df653a&newsId=d3adf9d2-db60-4f5c-b9c3-408df457d9f0) dressed in scrubs entered a seniors' residence in the West end of Ottawa, and proceeded into tenants' rooms and stole various items — Ottawa Police

Medical literature essentially follows the same convention:

> A 20-year-old Caucasian [*female*](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-A-20-year-old-Caucasian-female-presented-with-vitiligo-on-the-knees-with-the-right_fig5_234125102) presented with vitiligo on the knees, with the right knee involved more than the left knee.
>
> 54-year-old [*male*](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/54-year-old-male-presented-with-difficulty-in-breathing-and-was-diagnosed-with-asthma_fig10_281340539) presented with difficulty in breathing and was diagnosed with asthma. — Research Gate

What the language of police and physicians have in common is that they use *male* and *female* purely as physical descriptives. While this usage may seem impersonal and antiseptic, it is not insulting or demeaning.

This is not to say that the two words cannot be used in such a way:

> One of the most disturbing things you can discover, is that some [*female*](http://totallyhermedia.co.uk/women-who-flirt-with-unavailable-men/) who you don’t even know has been flirting with your man. The truth is that you should not blame the man, as it may not be his fault. — “Women Who Flirt With Unavailable Men,” Totally Her Media (UK)
>
> The next defining influence on my life was feminism. Its first glad morning, in the mid- to late Sixties, was thrilling. Here were women (not girls) who were no longer content to attach themselves like limpets to some [*male*](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/beware-the-march-of-liberal-thought-police-1483014.html); who wanted to forge their own lives and earn their own mortgages; who thought — no, dammit, knew — they were as good as men. — Angela Lambert, “Beware the march of liberal thought police,” *The Independent*, 5 July 1993.

In social contexts, reducing a man or woman to either gender or the purely physical can be demeaning, but not always so:

> The New Man was once a radical way to describe a [*male*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-25943326) who wholeheartedly accepted equality in domestic life. — “Whatever happened to the term New Man?” BBC News, 30 Jan. 2014.

Curiously enough, while addressing a male as “man,” in either slang or more formal English, is neutral without further context, addressing a woman simply as “woman” is *always* patronizing and insulting:

> “Now see here, [*woman*](https://books.google.de/books?id=2QRPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT211&dq=%22See+here,+Woman%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl7vrH5PTfAhWpsqQKHXb1DkgQ6AEIMDAC),”he said. “I don't know who you are, but I assure you that I have nothing but this boy’s best interests in mind.” — Greg Funaro,  *Alistair Grim's Odditorium*, 2015.

***Klingons***

Klingons have the distinction of being the only Star Trek humanoids adequately represented in a [Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Klingon+woman%2CKlingon+man%2CKlingon+female%2CKlingon+male&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKlingon%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKlingon%20female%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKlingon%20male%3B%2Cc0), but even here, *Klingon man* does not appear, which means the term returns less than 40 hits. *Klingon woman*, however, is by far the most represented:

[image]

This suggests that for writers in the Star Trek universe, Klingons are by default male; females have to be specified:

> This was, after all, a young [*Klingon woman*](https://books.google.de/books?id=yPxCqZyBNs0C&pg=PA43&dq=%22klingon+woman%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUlZaYhvXfAhURy6QKHQAcCbwQ6AEIJjAA). He supposed Kalrind would be considered attractive by a Klingon. In fact, Kirk could even see her attractiveness, if he made the effort to see her face as a Klingon would. — David Dvorkin, *Timetrap*, 1988, 43.

Though the Romulans have a fairly egalitarian — though fascist — culture, *Romulan woman* is the only term that shows up in an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Romulan+male,Romulan+man,Romulan+woman,Romulan+femaile&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRomulan%20woman%3B%2Cc0t1;,Romulan%20woman;,c0), suggesting the same male default.

*Klingon female* appears in the purely descriptive sense, as half of a male-female behavioral pair, or simply as a synonym:

> When a [*Klingon female*](https://books.google.de/books?id=oorXZWNSfrcC&q=%22klingon+female%22&dq=%22klingon+female%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSioPHjPXfAhVPMewKHdLcDdI4ChDoAQg6MAQ) wishes to divorce her mate, she simply declares “N 'Gos tlhogh cha! ” Translation: “Our marriage is done!” Oh, and then she belts him ...  — Michael Jan Friedman, Robert Greenberger,  *Q's Guide to the Continuum*, 1988, 38.
>
> A [*Klingon female*](https://books.google.de/books?id=B5AiSVBw7nMC&pg=PT175&dq=%22klingon+female%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzjfH7jvXfAhVRh6YKHfTtB70Q6AEIJjAA) would address someone as maqoch only if she intended to insult him or her. A Klingon male with any honor at all would never address a female as maqoch. The word maqoch itself may derive from may' qoch (literally, “battle partner”), so perhaps it originally meant something like “war buddy.” — Mark Okrand, *Klingon for the Galactic Traveler*, 2011.
>
> Kira frowned and turned back toward the older Klingon *[female](https://books.google.de/books?id=DVXxmpQj5U4C&pg=PA298&dq=Kira%20%22Klingon%20female%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9o9zGrvffAhULjSwKHW70DLIQ6AEIKDAA)*. — *Day of Honor* (anthology), 1999, 298.

The first two examples are drawn from non-narrative works where the use of male and female give the passages the air of cultural anthropology, as if the Klingons were some jungle tribe “discovered” in the 19th c. While this usage, then and now, may betray cultural bias, it is free of affect, which, of course, makes it all the more insidious when applied to real people rather than inhabitants of a fictive sci-fi universe.

Comment: "while addressing a male as “man,” in either slang or more formal English, is neutral without further context, addressing a woman simply as “woman” is always patronizing and insulting:"  True, but "Boy" is much more universally derogative than 'Girl'

Comment: Love the answer. Question from pure curiosity: would it be possible to search episode scripts or official media transcripts to gauge how often "Klingon woman," "Klingon female," and similar appellations are used in the shows and films?

Comment: The AP Style Guide says not to use "male" and "female" unless it is strictly necessary or in quotes. It's definitely kinda weird, but not universally demeaning (as you said). i can quote from my copy when i get home.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: Screenplays and filmscripts are rarely published, much less posted online.

Comment: @AzorAhai: I can see how the AP would react to the overuse of coptalk in newspapers.

Comment: There seems to be an odd gap in the English language for a feminine equivalents for "man" (as in "Hey man, what's up?") and "guy" (as in "He's a pretty cool guy."). I wonder how that happened.

Comment: My experience is that using "male" (an adjective, alone) as noun meaning "man" (male human) seems to be mostly an Americanism. Use of "male" without an accompanying species is almost an instance of [lexiphanicism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexiphanicism) in my opinion.

Comment: This one takes the biscuit: "Klingons have the distinction of being the only Star Trek humanoids adequately represented in a Google N-Gram." Your answers are always a joy to read... and great answers to boot!

Comment: I would say that "girl" is insulting, just in a different way, "boy" is associated with deliberate emasculation (see black men in the american south), where "girl" is often used interchangeably with woman, in a way that ignores the adulthood of the subject

Comment: You should see what the differences are when you prepend 'Human'. I see "human female" used by aliens in narrative works to suggest unfamiliarity and detachment on the part of the alien. I suppose the comparisons to "Human man" and "Human woman" are similar, although I would guess that these terms appear far more commonly since they are not a star trek exclusive.

Answer (score 5):

**Man and woman refers only to members of the species Homo Sapiens**. It is not a generic gender term that can apply to other species.

Further - because the Klingon world is made up, and we don’t know their language, then the writer is not able to say, for example ‘Vardikon’ for ‘Klingon male’ and ‘Komptree’ for ‘Klingon Female’ - as we don’t know those Klingon words - for ‘woman and man - in Klingon’.

And, if the author decides to teach us those words, there’s quite a lot s/he has to write. Which then doesn’t work if a reader dips into a later section of the book - having missed the explanation.

So that’s why the author is probably using ‘Klingon female’ and ‘the male’ etc.

It’s not derogatory in English.

It can be used to artistically emphasise aspects of gender - say, to contrast - for example ‘the female stood before him, battered, frail, bloodied, as the giant raised his hand...’ Contrasting her as ‘weaker’ in comparison to ‘the giant’ by emphasising her gender. Also potentially making a broader statement about ‘womankind’ at the same time.

The thing is that ‘woman’ and ‘man’ refer to ‘humans’, not to Klingons. Only humans can be ‘woman and man’. Man-man and womb-man - woman.

If you used ‘female’ in a more mundane situation like ‘the female shop assistant came up to me and she said...’ then that’s ok and not derogatory. It might be used to differentiate her from, say, ‘the male shop assistant’.

Man - ‘ a member of the species Homo Sapiens...’

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/man?s=t

Comment: This is simply not correct. Even outside of sci-fi entirely, man and woman can refer to other hominids. E.g. https://www.theguardian.com/science/2016/feb/17/oldest-known-case-of-neanderthal-human-sex-revealed-by-dna-test

Comment: We do know the Klingon language despite it also being "made up".  The words for man and woman in the Klingon language are loD and be' respectively.

Comment: Dictionary.com has "1: an adult male person, as distinguished from a boy or a woman. " and only the second and 3rd meaning refer to human. Also "person: ... 5: a self-conscious or rational being. "

Comment: If I may furthermore point out that the 'etymology' of woman (womb + man) given here is simply wrong. It is a combination of 'wif' (cf. for example to "wife" in English or "Weib" in German) and man.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/woman

Comment: Worth pointing out that klingons in the stories often referred to their own males and females as "men and women". Most of the Male/Female stuff was cross-species. Ferengi particularly like to discuss "Hooman Females". I always took it as slightly derogatory. That other sentient species were essentially being regarded as a kind of animal.

Comment: @PatricHartmann It's the same nonsense as the female/male thing, where people think that the etymology of "female" is something like "not-male". While male comes from the Latin "mas" (which means male), while female comes from the Latin "femina". And both versions are based on the diminutive froms of these words, "masculus" and "femella", which both (if you drop enough consonants) have the form (fe)m*l*, with the asteriscs standing for some vovel. Shift the vovels enough and you end up with male and female.

Comment: And ‘wife’ apparently comes fron proto-Germanic ‘wiban’, meaning ‘weave, plait’. http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/etymology.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fpiet&text_number=1422&root=config

Answer (score 3):

There's a specific reason this formation is used in Science Fiction --it's meant to emphasize the alien nature of the speaker, and the fact that the speaker and human beings are of different species.  It's a deliberately distancing and dehumanizing/depersonalizing locution, an oft-used writer's shorthand to denote an alien perspective.

Given that, you wouldn't use it in ordinary conversation.  It would typically be insulting in English, just as it is in German.

With that said, there are exceptions.  "Females" is sometimes used as a playful equivalent to "women" in contemporary black American slang, but usually only if the speaker is male.  Also, as @KarlG indicated, it can be used in institutional or scientific descriptions (perhaps because of the depersonalizing effect, and perhaps to avoid the numerous additional connotations of "man" and "woman").

Comment: It's sad that we see distance/alienness as insulting/derogatory.

Comment: @Chris Sunami supports Monica When there's a specific reason that formation is used in sci-fi, is that always true, sometimes true or what? If you're truly suggesting there is a single, mandated reason then by all means feel free to justify that but at the same time, feel free to drop it for lack of support. My suggestion is there is no specific - certainly no single - reason but rather, everything depends on what a particular author meant in a particular story. Does that not work for you?